# How to create a function which converts an array into a typed object in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I am new to typescript, and I am trying to write a function which I can use to convert arrays from a web request response to an object. I have written a function, and a unit test which is passing:

```
import { parseDataToObject } from './ParseResults';

interface ITestPerson {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

describe('parseDataToObject', () => {
  // Ommitted simple cases such as testing for empty arrays etc...

  describe('passed data and keys array', () => {
    it('returns an array of converted objects matching an interface', () => {
      const testData = [['matt', 25], ['dom', 45]];
      const testKeys = ['name', 'age'];
      const expectToBe: Array<ITestPerson> = [{ name: 'matt', age: 25 }, { name: 'dom', age: 45 }];
      expect(parseDataToObject<ITestPerson>({ data: testData, keys: testKeys })).toStrictEqual(expectToBe);
    });
  });
});
```

And here is the function I have written:

```
export function parseDataToObject<T>({ data, keys } : {data: any[][], keys: Array<string>}): Array<T> {
  if (data.length === 0) return [];
  if (data[0].length !== keys.length) throw new Error("Keys array length doesn't match the data count");
  return data.map((dataArr: Array<any>): T => {
    let object = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      object[keys[i]] = dataArr[i];
    }
    return object;
  });
}
//above is ParseResults.ts
```

The function works as expected in jest so it seems to be working as far as JavaScript functionality, but my issues are with the extra typescript types.

I hope it is clear I want to convert an array of arrays of data to an array of objects which are typed. An example of the data returned back from the API I am using is:

```
[[1622073600000,"39241.92000000","40411.14000000","37134.27000000","38529.98000000","86547.15879400",1622159999999,"3361413526.05354346",2102182,"42256.01280100","1641681553.52913720","0"],...]
```

Everything looks good so far with my unit test passing. I then try and use it in my application by the following:

```
// Binance.ts
export interface IKlineData {
  openTime: number;
  open: string;
  high: string;
  low: string
  close: string;
  volume: string;
  closeTiime: number;
  quoteAssetVol: string;
  numTrades: number;
  takerBuyBaseAssetVol: string;
  takerBuyQuoteAssetVol: string;
  ignore: string;
}
const klineDataKeys = [
  'openTime',
  'open',
  'high',
  'low',
  'close',
  'volume',
  'closeTiime',
  'quoteAssetVol',
  'numTrades',
  'takerBuyBaseAssetVol',
  'takerBuyQuoteAssetVol',
  'ignore'];


const result = await axiosGet(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=${symbol}&interval=1d`);
// following is line 68
const klineData: Array<IKlineData> = parseDataToObject<IKlineData>({data: result.data, keys: klineDataKeys});
```

But I am getting the following compilation errors with the typescript compiler:

```
src/index.d/Binance.ts(68,75): error TS2322: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to ty
pe 'any[][]'.
src/index.d/binance.d/ParseResults.ts(7,7): error TS7053: Element implicitly has an
 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.
src/index.d/binance.d/ParseResults.ts(9,5): error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignab
le to type 'T'.
  'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to '{}'
```

I can kind of see that the way I am constructing the object in the `parseDataToObject` function isn't safe, but I am not sure exactly what to do to fix my issues.

Please find below a minimum reproducible example

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios';

export interface IResponseData<T> {
  status: number;
  data: T;
}

export interface IKlineData {
  openTime: number;
  open: string;
  high: string;
  low: string
  close: string;
  volume: string;
  closeTiime: number;
  quoteAssetVol: string;
  numTrades: number;
  takerBuyBaseAssetVol: string;
  takerBuyQuoteAssetVol: string;
  ignore: string;
}
const klineDataKeys = [
  'openTime',
  'open',
  'high',
  'low',
  'close',
  'volume',
  'closeTiime',
  'quoteAssetVol',
  'numTrades',
  'takerBuyBaseAssetVol',
  'takerBuyQuoteAssetVol',
  'ignore'];

function axiosGet<T>(url: string): Promise<IResponseData<T>> {
  const axiosConfig: AxiosRequestConfig = {
    method: 'get',
    url,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };

  return new Promise<IResponseData<T>>((resolve, reject) => axios(axiosConfig)
    .then((response) => {
      resolve({ data: response.data, status: response.status });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      reject(error);
    }));
}

(async function () {
    const result = await axiosGet(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1d`);
    const klineData: Array<IKlineData> = parseDataToObject<IKlineData>({data: result.data, keys: klineDataKeys});
}());


function parseDataToObject<T>({ data, keys } : {data: any[][], keys: Array<string>}): Array<T> {
  if (data.length === 0) return [];
  if (data[0].length !== keys.length) throw new Error("Keys array length doesn't match the data count");
  return data.map((dataArr: Array<any>): T => {
    let object = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      object[keys[i]] = dataArr[i];
    }
    return <T>object;
  });
}
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link to code)](https://tsplay.dev/ND5MVm), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Comment: @jcalz I have made one, am I best sharing it by just editing the original post?

Comment: Yes, editing the post with the [mcve] is a good idea. 

Comment: @jcalz I have done that now, sorry about that

Comment: So, when you call `const result = await axiosGet(...)`, what do you expect the type of `result` to be?  Your `axiosGet()` function is generic in a type parameter `T`, but there's nowhere from which the compiler could infer the type for `T`, right?  The compiler falls back to `unknown`, and then you get that error when you call `parseDataToObject()`.  Perhaps you want to call `await axiosGet<any[][]>(...)` to suppress the error?  Frankly I'm not sure what is motivating your use of generics here, or how these generics are better than using `any`.  Can you explain what the intent is?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for taking the time to look at my issue, it is much appreciated. Thanks for the suggestion about `axiosGet<any[][]>` . As for why I am doing this over just using the `any` type... pardon my possible ignorance but I thought the whole point of using TypeScript over JavaScript was to add types to things to allow the compiler to catch more bugs? In Scala for example I would parse API data into a case class so I can work with it as a type. If I am just going to use the `any` for API data I don't really understand why you'd use typescript at all. Maybe I misunderstand the `any` type?

Comment: Let's say I have two functions, like this: `declare function foo(): any` and `declare function bar<T>(): T`.  They are both not type safe, in very similar ways.  Is it really possible for a function `foo()` to return a value of any type the caller wants, without having to tell the `foo` implementation anything about such a type?  Should you trust `const x: string = foo();`?  No, you shouldn't.  And is it really possible for a function `bar()` to return a value of any type the caller wants?  I can call `const x = bar<string>()`, but how does `bar()` know it's supposed to return a `string`?

Comment: If `any` makes you question the usefulness of TypeScript, then so should any function that promises to return a value of a generic type with no input of that type or related to that type.  Something like `<T>(x: T)=>T` is fine (you can return the input); something like `<T>(x: Array<T>) => T | undefined` is fine (you can return one element of the array), but `<T>(x: string) => T` is just magically producing a value of caller-specified `T` out of thin air.  I think `fetch()`-like code might often be like this, but it's not any safer than `any`.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for that explanation, that does make sense to me. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the help from @jcalz and also some more debugging myself I have managed to get it to compile. I needed to set the generic type when I was calling my axios get function:

```
const result = await axiosGet<any[][]>(`https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1d`);
```

And then I needed just to give a hint to my object where I dynamically set its properties that its key types are a string:

```
let object: {[index: string]: any} = {};
```